# Invalid option name ("--modules-folder=/layers/google.nodejs.yarn/yarn_modules/node_modules") while deploying nextjs app to google app engine

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, yarnpkg, next.js13

I followed those steps:

- `distDir: 'build'` in `next.config.js`
- modified `package.json`

  ```json
  {
    "name": "SHOP",
    "version": "1.0.8",
    "description": "Next.js high-performance e-commerce websites.",
    "keywords": [
      "boundless",
      "boundless-commerce",
      "cms",
      "headless",
      "ecommerce",
      "api",
      "checkout",
      "typescript",
      "cms",
      "cart",
      "nextjs",
      "theme"
    ],
    "main": "index.js",
    "repository": "https://github.com/namcao502/SHOP",
    "author": "Nam <namcao502@gmail.com>",
    "license": "MIT",
  **  "scripts": {
      "analyze": "cross-env ANALYZE=true next build",
      "dev": "next dev",
      "build": "next build",
      "start": "next start",
      "gcp-build": "",
      "deploy": "gcloud config set project winter-monolith-405012 && gcloud app deploy app.yaml --version=0-1-2 --quiet",
      "lint": "npx eslint --ext .ts --ext .tsx . && npx stylelint ./styles"
    },**
    "dependencies": {
      "@fontsource/roboto": "^4.5.3",
      "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.15.4",
      "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.36",
      "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
      "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
      "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.16",
      "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.2",
      "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.7.1",
      "@types/js-cookie": "^3.0.1",
      "@types/lodash": "^4.14.178",
      "@types/nprogress": "^0.2.0",
      "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.25",
      "@types/react-transition-group": "^4.4.6",
      "@use-gesture/vanilla": "^10.2.5",
      "animate.css": "^4.1.1",
      "body-scroll-lock": "^4.0.0-beta.0",
      "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
      "boundless-api-client": "^0.1.4",
      "boundless-checkout-react": "^1.1.5",
      "clsx": "^1.1.1",
      "currency.js": "^2.0.4",
      "js-cookie": "^3.0.1",
      "lodash": "^4.17.21",
      "next": "^13.4.19",
      "nprogress": "^0.2.0",
      "photoswipe": "^5.3.8",
      "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
      "qs": "^6.10.2",
      "rc-slider": "^9.7.5",
      "react": "^18.2.0",
      "react-bootstrap": "^2.8.0",
      "react-content-loader": "^6.1.0",
      "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
      "react-photoswipe-gallery": "^2.2.7",
      "react-redux": "^8.1.2",
      "react-transition-group": "^4.4.5",
      "sass": "^1.45.0",
      "sharp": "^0.32.5",
      "swiper": "8",
      "typescript": "^4.5.4",
      "xmlbuilder": "^15.1.1",
      "yarn": "^1.22.21"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      "@next/bundle-analyzer": "^12.3.4",
      "@types/body-scroll-lock": "^3.1.0",
      "@types/lodash": "^4.14.178",
      "@types/node": "^17.0.0",
      "@types/qs": "^6.9.7",
      "@types/react": "^18.2.20",
      "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.7",
      "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.9.1",
      "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.9.1",
      "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
      "eslint": "^8.6.0",
      "eslint-config-next": "^12.0.7",
      "postcss": "^8.4.28",
      "stylelint": "^14.2.0",
      "stylelint-config-sass-guidelines": "^9.0.1",
      "stylelint-config-standard": "^24.0.0",
      "ts-node": "^10.4.0"
    },
    "engines": {
      "node": ">=16.8",
      "yarn": ">=1.x"
    }
  }
  ```
- `app.yaml`

  ```yaml
  runtime: nodejs
  env: flex
  runtime_config:
      operating_system: "ubuntu22"
  automatic_scaling:
      min_num_instances: 1
      max_num_instances: 10
      cool_down_period_sec: 180
      cpu_utilization:
          target_utilization: 0.9
  resources:
      cpu: 2
      memory_gb: 4.6
      disk_size_gb: 10
  network:
      name: default
  ```
- `npm run build`
- `npm run deploy`

And I got this error:

```
Build failed: Unknown Syntax Error: Invalid option name ("--modules-folder=/layers/google.nodejs.yarn/yarn_modules/node_modules").

$ yarn install [--json] [--immutable] [--immutable-cache] [--refresh-lockfile] [--check-cache] [--check-resolutions] [--inline-builds] [--mode #0]; Error ID: 12c8ef4a
```

I tried both Google App Engine and Firebase hosting, the errors are still the same. Please help me deploy it. Vercel is fine btw but I want to host it on Google App Engine.

Comment: Did you solve it somehow? Having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by removing `yarn` from my `engines` attribute in the `package.json`. I still use `yarn`, just removed it from `package.json`s `engines` attribute.

So, this is my setup for `firebase` which is working fine.

**package.json:**

```
{
  "main": "src/firebaseApp.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": "18",
    - "yarn": "1" // Deleted this line
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^12.0.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^4.6.0",
  },
  "scripts": {
    "deploy:api": "firebase deploy --only functions"
  }
}
```

**firebase.json:**

```
{
  "functions": [
    {
      "source": ".",
      "codebase": "default",
      "ignore": [".git", "firebase-debug.log", "firebase-debug.*.log"]
    }
  ]
}
```